# Generate QR Codes several time with name tags and logos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qr-code

I need to generate QR codes to create IDs.

I have the following `div` for the ID design:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table id="tb">
            <tr><th style="font-size: 2em">Name:</th></tr>
            <tr><th style="font-size: 2em">Date of Birth:</th></tr>
            <tr><th style="font-size: 2em" id="qrcode"></th></tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have 2 text boxes. The first one is to specify the number of QR needed, the second for the text that should be coded inside the QR:

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./qrcode.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = $("#number_of_card").val();
    var startingFrom = $("#start_number").val();

    while(total!==0)
    {
        $(this).append('tb')

        var codedId = parseInt(total)+parseInt(startingFrom);
        new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), ""+codedId);
        total--;
    }
</script>
```

I used the following library: [QR Code](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/).

What I need is to duplicate all the div so each qr code generated should have a name and date of birth div, which I can not reach.

The full script is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/w2qgbjLf/

Comment: You are generating QR code in memory, but not assigning/appending it to DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle had an error, so you were not seeing QRs, see this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gv9dx1sh/16/

```
var total = $("#number_of_card").val();
var startingFrom = $("#start_number").val();

    while(total !== 0)
    {
      $('body').append(`<div><div>Name:</div><div>BirthDate</div><div id='qrcode${total}'></div></div>`);
      var codedId = parseInt(total)+ parseInt(startingFrom);
      new QRCode(document.getElementById(`qrcode${total}`), "" + codedId);
      total--;
    }
```

Comment: I updated my fiddle. But your post didn't answer my question

Comment: Do you want div inside QR code? or you want div's value to generate QR? @droidnation

Comment: I need each div to contain a name, a date of birth and a qr code. So if I specified that I need 10 QR, and I need to generate 10 divs containing these informations.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. If  need to generate them horizontally, how can I do it ?

Comment: You have to write some css, just check it in stackoverflow, display inline or float left or flex-box